# QUERY speed with limit and milion records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi i have a 7milion records db table for testing query speed.

I tested up my 2 queries which are the same query with different limit parametres:

query 1 -

```
SELECT    * 
FROM      table 
LIMIT     20, 50;
```

query 2 -

```
SELECT    * 
FROM      table 
LIMIT     6000000, 6000030;
```

query exec times are:

1. query 1 - 0.006 sec
2. query 2 - 5.500 sec

In both of these queries, I am fetching same number of records, but in the second case it's taking more time. Can someone please explain the reasons behind this?

Comment: Do you have any indexing? Do you have a primary key? If you don't have any then this makes sense to me.

Comment: @amir  if no indexing for both queries should be he same test not? or if i put index second query will take same time of first query?

Comment: if you have no index at all then I don't think MySQL can skip the first 6000000 rows. You have to have at least some primary index for it to skip rows. Maybe someone else can confirm this? We could also test this.

Comment: i'm almost ready to run up new test with indexing let's see wht will return ;) i'll tell you

Comment: tested up with index key: query 1 0.08 sec query 2 4.50 sec ... little improvment but scenario is the same :P

Comment: Wow good find. Now I must really know what is causing these. The idea is if you do WHERE id > 600000 LIMIT 30 should be the same query right?

Comment: omg i just tested up your idea :O in case of no offset so : where id > n + limit(30)  - query 1 0.05 sec query 2 0.07            :OOOOOOOOOO incredible :OOOO

Comment: Did you even look at my answer? The second limit parameter is the number of rows to return!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does MYSQL higher LIMIT offset slow the query down?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481388/why-does-mysql-higher-limit-offset-slow-the-query-down)

Comment: sbaaaang, you are not fetching the same number of rows....you are fetching 6000030 in the query 2....the right query to skip 6000000 rows would be: SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 6000000, 30;  the second parameter of LIMIT is how many rows to retrieve not a superior limit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without looking into it too closely, my assumption is that this occurs because the first query only has to read to the 50th record to return results, whereas the second query has to read six million before returning results. Basically, the first query just shorts out quicker.

I would assume that this has an incredible amount to do with the makeup of the table - field types and keys, etc.

If a record is made up of fixed-length fields (e.g. CHAR vs. VARCHAR), then the DBMS can just calculate where the nth record starts and jumps there. If its variable length, then you would have to read the records to determine where the nth record starts. Similarly, I'd further assume that tables which have appropriate primary keys would be quicker to query than those without such keys.

Comment: that is what i think about for sure :( and i think no solutions for that right? just query caching :(

Comment: @user I can't think of a solution off the top of my head. The only thing I could think of - and this is a **total hack** - would be to add a datetime field to mark the creation of the record, then add an index on that field, and then sort on that field in the query. I haven't tested this, but you **might** be able to trick the database to limit based on that key, which could make the query run in O(1) time, but I wouldn't count on it. Also, it's not quite the query you have above, because default sort order is undefined by spec - You'd be emulating a common convention rather than spec;  YMMV.

Comment: thanks for hack i will try smethings anyway i was just asking the differences to understand better how mysql process db records ;)

Answer (score 6):

I think the slowdown is tied to the fact you are using limits with offsets and are querying the table with no additional context for indexing.  Its possible the first is just faster because it can get to the offset quicker.

Comment: some googling suggests that mysql counts each row until it gets to the offset.. so guessing it just takes longer to get to the xxxxx offest compared to the 20th row.

Comment: that's true indexing there is not but is not a speed problem i was just asking about the difference ;)

Answer (score 4):

It's the difference between returning 50 rows and 6000030 rows (or ~1million rows since you said there were only 7million rows).

> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, **and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return**. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Also, I think you're looking for 30 row pages so your queries should be using 30 as the second parameter in the limit clause.

```
SELECT    * 
FROM      table 
LIMIT     20, 30;

SELECT    * 
FROM      table 
LIMIT     6000000, 30;
```

Comment: The 2nd param could be a contributing factor because the query is in fact returning many more rows.. I dont think its fair at all to say this does not provide an answer.. his answer is that returning a bajillion rows takes longer.. and its probably partially correct.

Comment: ok ... so records in that range are parsed too or skipped? i think they are parsed either there will be not difference, while difference exist , right?

Comment: offset is minimal compared to row count.  
I was digging up the reference

Comment: @dotjoe Cool, apologies for the downvote then - I think this answer is quite valid