# Slow MySQL limit select

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, sql-order-by, limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does MYSQL higher LIMIT offset slow the query down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481388/why-does-mysql-higher-limit-offset-slow-the-query-down)

I have a page and I would like to sort posts in it from top to bottom by the amount of votes each post has.

I have millions of records, and the query gets really slow. it takes few good minutes to get the results.

This is fine:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table` ORDER BY `votes` LIMIT 0,20;
```

This will take ages:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table` ORDER BY `votes` LIMIT 100000,20;
```

I am not even talking about setting it to 1,000,000 and more.

Any ideas on how to make this faster?

Comment: Did you already look at what `EXPLAIN` tells you about these queries?  Problems with missing indexes etc should be pretty clear in the output of explain.

Comment: Seems like it is using indexes. `id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1  SIMPLE  quotes  index  NULL  votes  8  NULL  1020  Using index`

Comment: Well, for some reason my queries are a-bit faster now. the query can now take anywhere from 5 to 20 seconds, which is too long. any ideas? using the method from the post you linked me to, does nothing really.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend caching the result every hour or so.

http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/output-caching-for-beginners/

I believe the query is heavy and will lagg anyway, but with caching it'll show cached result and update (run query) once a hour.

Correct me, if I'm wrong.