# Rails: Get next / previous record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My app has Photos that belong to Users.

In a photo#show view I'd like to show "More from this user", and show a next and previous photo from that user. I would be fine with these being the next/previous photo in `id` order or the next/previous photo in `created_at` order.

How would you write that kind of query for one next / previous photo, or for multiple next / previous photos?

Comment: This gem perfectly worked for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25712023/683157

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Try this:

```
class User
  has_many :photos
end


class Photo
  belongs_to :user

  def next
    user.photos.where("id > ?", id).first
  end

  def prev
    user.photos.where("id < ?", id).last
  end

end
```

Now you can:

```
photo.next
photo.prev
```

Comment: prev does not work properly this way, should be user.photos.where("id < ?", id).last, well, thank's anyway

Comment: @igrek I have fixed the answer. Generally, I avoid using `last` call as it has performance implications if you have a big data set(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481388/why-does-mysql-higher-limit-offset-slow-the-query-down). I use the `ORDER BY id DESC` clause to get to the last rows.

Comment: how about using limit(1) ?

Comment: @KourindouHime, the `first` method limits the result set to `LIMIT 1`. The `first` method here is different than the first method on an array.

Comment: @igrek, I have changed the solution to use `first` and `last` as I noticed that in latest version of rails `first` and `last` adds proper sorting.

Answer (score 24):

It lead me to a solution for my problem as well. I was trying to make a next/prev for an item, no associations involved. ended up doing something like this in my model:

```
  def next
    Item.where("id > ?", id).order("id ASC").first || Item.first
  end

  def previous
    Item.where("id < ?", id).order("id DESC").first || Item.last
  end
```

This way it loops around, from last item it goes to the first one and the other way around.
I just call `@item.next` in my views afterwards.

Comment: Awesome for cycle iteration.

Comment: Nice, was looking for a cycle as well!

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this is a change in Rails 3.2+, but instead of:

```
model.where("id < ?", id).first
```

for the previous.  You have to do

```
.where("id > ?", id).last
```

It seems that the "order by" is wrong, so first give you the first record in the DB, because if you have 3 items lower than the current, [1,3,4], then the "first" is 1, but that last is the one you ware looking for.  You could also apply a sort to after the where, but thats an extra step.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  scope :next, lambda {|id| where("id > ?",id).order("id ASC") } # this is the default ordering for AR
  scope :previous, lambda {|id| where("id < ?",id).order("id DESC") }

  def next
    user.photos.next(self.id).first
  end

  def previous
    user.photos.previous(self.id).first
  end
end
```

Then you can:

```
photo.previous
photo.next
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work, and I think it's more efficient than the other solutions in that it doesn't retrieve *every record* above or below the current one just to get to the next or previous one:

```
def next
  # remember default order is ascending, so I left it out here
  Photo.offset(self.id).limit(1).first
end

def prev
  # I set limit to 2 because if you specify descending order with an 
  # offset/limit query, the result includes the offset record as the first
  Photo.offset(self.id).limit(2).order(id: :desc).last
end
```

This is my first answer ever posted on StackOverflow, and this question is pretty old...I hope somebody sees it :)

Comment: This solution does not work if the underlying Database IDs are not regular which is a common use case. 

for example 

if my record IDs are `[3, 10, 11, 13, 14]` 

and if I want to find the next element to `id => 3`

then the yielded result is `offset(3) => [13,14]`.

This behaviour is explained clearly in docs `offset => Specifies the number of rows to skip before returning rows.`

Answer (score 4):

Modify your app/models/application_record.rb to the following code:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def next
    self.class.where("id > ?", id).order("id ASC").first || self.class.first
  end

  def previous
   self.class.where("id < ?", id).order("id DESC").first || self.class.last
  end
end
```

Then you can use next() and previous() in all your models.

Comment: Works great. You might want to implement this on your model class instead, that way you can scope the query in a way that's consistent with your business logic (next/previous published article, for example).

Answer (score 2):

You can pass some options into the where method:

For the next photo:

```
Photo.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :created_at > current_photo.created_at).order("created_at").first
```

Previous photo

```
Photo.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :created_at < current_photo.created_at).order("created_at").last
```

I may have the first/last mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [Nexter](https://github.com/charly/nexter). 
It works on any dynamically created scope instead of relying on one hardcoded in your model.

Comment: I've created gem with the same behaviour, but the other approach: https://github.com/dmitry/proximal_records

Answer (score 1):

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  default_scope { order('published_at DESC, id DESC') }

  def next
    current = nil
    user.photos.where('published_at >= ?', published_at).each do |p|
      if p.id == id then break else current = p end
    end
    return current
  end

  def previous
    current = nil
    user.photos.where('published_at <= ?', published_at).reverse.each do |p|
      if p.id == id then break else current = p end
    end
    return current
  end
end
```

I found that the answers already here did not serve my case. Imagine that you want a previous or next based on the date published, but some photos are published on the same date. This version will loop through the photos in the order they are rendered on the page, and take the ones before and after the current one in the collection.