# rails activerecord find next record with attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm a rails beginner and I have an image detail view where just the image is displayed with a link.

The link url should redirect to the next image if it has the attribute show_image == false and if next image exists.

How can I do it?

at the moment it looks like this:

```
  - if @picture.next.present? && (@picture.category.title == @picture.next.category.title)
    %a.picture-show{ :href => "#{@picture.next.id}" }
      = image_tag @picture.image.normal.url
  - else
    %a.picture-show{ :href => picture_path(params[:category_slug], @next.id) }
      = image_tag @picture.image.normal.url
```

Comment: Is your current logic working, and you're just looking to add another piece to it, or is it not acting as expected as it stands?

Comment: I have no clue how to do it.
I guess I would have to loop through it or something

Comment: What's being shown right now?

Comment: I want the link URL to the next record which has the attribute show_image == false. If it has true, than I want the next

Comment: That logic would be in your model, not your view. Take a look at this post for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394088/rails-get-next-previous-record you'd need to modify your query a little to find the next one with that flag, but the core would remain the same

Comment: ah thanks, I guess that could be the right way, I'll check it

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that is changing is the url of the image so you can use a helper to figure it out

in you view

```
%a.picture-show{ :href => next_image_url(@picture) }
  = image_tag @picture.image.normal.url
```

in your helper

```
def next_image_url(picture)
  if picture.next.present?
    picture_path picture.next
  else
    picture_path picture
  end
end
```

if you have not calculate the method 'next' yet then it would be something like this

```
def next
  Picture.where('id > ?' self.id).order('id desc').where(show_image: true).first
end
```

Comment: nearly done, I just wanted now to check if the next picture has attrbute "show_image" == false.
Can I do it like this:

Picture.where('id > ?' self.id).where('show_image' false).order('id desc').first

Comment: I want to know where does it redirect to, the picture show page? If you have a show_image attr in your model, then you can also put that logic in the next method.

Comment: I had a the following in my picture.rb:

scope :next, lambda {|id| where("id > ?",id).where(show_image: false).order("id ASC") }

  def next
    Picture.next(self.id).first
  end

Comment: Minor correction to your `next` method. As written it will return the first last record created (i.e. the record with the greatest `id`). It should be rewritten as follows: `Picture.where('id > ?' self.id).order('id asc').where(show_image: true).first`