# Rails best way to get previous and next active record object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to get the previous and next active record objects with Rails. I did it, but don't know if it's the right way to do that.

What I've got:

Controller:

```
@product = Product.friendly.find(params[:id])

order_list = Product.select(:id).all.map(&:id)

current_position = order_list.index(@product.id)

@previous_product = @collection.products.find(order_list[current_position - 1]) if order_list[current_position - 1]
@next_product = @collection.products.find(order_list[current_position + 1]) if order_list[current_position + 1]

@previous_product ||= Product.last
@next_product ||= Product.first
```

product_model.rb

```
default_scope -> {order(:product_sub_group_id => :asc, :id => :asc)}
```

So, the problem here is that I need to go to my database and get all this ids to know who is the previous and the next.

Tried to use the gem [order_query](https://github.com/glebm/order_query), but it did not work for me and I noted that it goes to the database and fetch all the records in that order, so, that's why I did the same but getting only the ids.

All the solutions that I found was with simple order querys. Order by id or something like a priority field.

Comment: Which DB are you using? PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There's no easy out-of-the-box solution.**

A little dirty, but working way is carefully sorting out what conditions are there for finding next and previous items. With `id` it's quite easy, since all `id`s are different, and [Rails Guy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25666841/2076787) describes just that: in `next` for a known `id` pick a first entry with a larger `id` (if results are ordered by `id`, as per defaults). More than that - his answer hints to place `next` and `previous` into the model class. Do so.

If there are **multiple order criteria**, things get **complicated**. Say, we have a set of rows sorted by `group` parameter first (which can possibly have equal values on different rows) and then by `id` (which id different everywhere, guaranteed). Results are ordered by **`group`** and then by **`id`** (both **ascending**), so we can possibly encounter two situations of getting the next element, it's the first from the list that has elements, that (so many *that*):

- have the **same `group`** and a **larger `id`**
- have **a larger `group`**

Same with previous element: you need the last one from the list

- have the **same `group`** and a **smaller `id`**
- have **a smaller `group`**

Those fetch **all** next and previous entries respectively. If you need only one, use Rails' `first` and `last` (as suggested by [Rails Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25666841/2076787)) or `limit(1)` (and be wary of the **asc/desc** ordering).

Comment: @glebm The author explicitly stated that he tried to use it. Still, `order_query` is **not** an out-of-the-box solution, it's a third-party library. I understand your concern, as the library's maintainer, it would be better to clarify with the author, what exactly didn't work.

Answer (score 39):

Write these methods in your `Product` model:

```
class Product

  def next
    self.class.where("id > ?", id).first
  end

  def previous
    self.class.where("id < ?", id).last
  end

end
```

Now you can do in your controller:

```
@product = Product.friendly.find(params[:id])

@previous_product = @product.next
@next_product = @product.previous
```

Please try it, but its not tested.
Thanks

Comment: The problem is that I'm not ordering by ID.

Comment: It's still a good example on where to put these methods. Can be put to use.

Comment: I agree. How do you call it in the view?

Comment: I up voted Rails Guy's answer, but wanted to address the questions about ordering by something other than id, e.g. created_at.
Per requests from @Mogsdad and others, I changed my answer to a comment.

To order by created_at, change the implementation of the suggested `next` method to include: `self.class.where("created_at > ?", created_at).order(created_at: :asc).first` and your `previous` method to include `self.class.where("created_at < ?", created_at).order(created_at: :asc).last`

Comment: Your solution helped me. So elegant.

Comment: thanks for the ordering solution, just what I needed.

Comment: Works, but you will have to add `.order('anything ASC')` after the .where query in case you order by something else than ID.

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be faster to do it with only two SQL requests, that only select two rows (and not the entire table). Considering that your default order is sorted by id (otherwise, force the sorting by id) :

```
@previous_product = Product.where('id < ?', params[:id]).last
@next_product = Product.where('id > ?', params[:id]).first
```

If the product is the last, then @next_product will be nil, and if it is the first, then, @previous_product will be nil.

Comment: The problem is that my order is not by the id and I need to maintain that way. default_scope -> {order(:product_sub_group_id => :asc, :id => :asc)}

Comment: Turns out, `first` and `last` acually do `LIMIT 1`. So it **doesn't** load tons of objects and only take one. It actually retrieves only one object. *Just a note.*

Comment: @WilliamWeckl then replace `id` with the field you are comparing, as long as there are no equal ordering values: multiple criteria can be achieved via a construct like `(> first) or (=first, >second)`.

Comment: Otherwise, maybe you could try something with row_number : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614666/mysql-get-row-position-in-order-by

Comment: @D-side my field that I use to order is a group of products, in my list I get all products ordered by groups, when the product is from same group, than I order by ID.

Comment: @Jean-Daube can I do that in postgres and with active record methods?

Comment: @WilliamWeckl I've reflected that as well, in a bit unclear way: you could form conditions like `(group_id = ? AND id > ?) OR group_id > ?`. A certainly not so clean solution...

Comment: @WilliamWeckl : Yes, it seems that row_number exists for postGre : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397121/how-to-show-row-numbers-in-postgresql-query

Unfortunately, I don't think you'll be able to handle it through clean active record methods. You will have to use Model.find_by_sql(...).

Comment: @D-side not so clean but still quite effective ! But when you have such nested conditions, shouldn't you start with the one that has the more chances to be true for the less efforts, so that you don't have to execute the second one ? (and therefore do  group_id > ? OR (group_id = ? AND id > ?) ) ??

Comment: @WilliamWeckl I doubt there's much room for optimization, since only one object will be fetched. I've ordered my conditions in the same order you might be ordering results in: same group first, next groups next.

Comment: @D-side I'm a little confused about what solution fits better. I understand the two solutions will work, but mine works too. Just working is not what I'm looking for.  
Your solution and Jean-Daube's solution looks like more performative than mine but, is there any rails way or other conventions to do something like that?

Comment: @WilliamWeckl I'm not aware of any standard way to achieve that. Since this can only (probably) be implemented manually, the Rails Way can only be obeyed in a sense of where to place that code. See another answer on how to pack these methods into the model class for easy referencing. You may even use `arel` to avoid plain SQL conditions if you want.

Comment: @D-side Did it. `.where('(products.product_sub_group_id = :product_sub_group_id and products.id > :id) OR products.product_sub_group_id > :product_sub_group_id',
    {:product_sub_group_id => self.product_sub_group_id, :id => self.id})` Haven't understand the advantages of using `AREL`. Wanna post it as answer to I can set as the solution?

Comment: @WilliamWeckl it's just Ruby way of writing SQL. 100% Ruby is a little easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

This is what [order_query](https://github.com/glebm/order_query) does. Please try the latest version, I can help if it doesn't work for you:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  order_query :my_order,
    [:product_sub_group_id, :asc], 
    [:id, :asc]     
  default_scope -> { my_order } 
end

@product.my_order(@collection.products).next
@collection.products.my_order_at(@product).next
```

This runs one query loading only the next record. [Read more on Github](https://github.com/glebm/order_query).