# Get succeeding object in cycled collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cycle

I have a collection of users which is ordered by their last name.

```
User.order(last_name: :asc)
```

I want to get the user suceeding another one (stored in variable), and if last in collection get the first.

Any better solutions to this than what I've done?

```
user # stored user object
users = User.order(last_name: :asc)
index = users.index {|item| item == user}
succeeding = if user == users[index].last then users[index].first else users[index + 1] end
```

Comment: Does this code work?

Comment: Do you see anything erroneous with it?

Comment: `user == users[index].last` or `user == users.last`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25674239/2076787 Look at this. With sorting first by last name and then by id this is pretty much it. The rest is provided in an already given answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user # stored user object
users = User.order(last_name: :asc)

succeeding = users[users.find_index(user)+1]||users.first
```