# Finding 'next posts' based on position integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a posts model with an integer column called 'position' to manually order them. On a post's show page I have a 'more posts' section with @more_posts.

```
@more_posts = @comment.posts.where("posts.id NOT IN (?)", @post.id).order("position").limit(2)
```

This gives me two unique posts but I'm not sure how to get the next two posts instead of the two highest positioned posts. Say the current post.id is 2, I'd like @more_posts to get posts 3 and 4.

(I'm using postgresql is production and sqlite in development.)

Comment: What is your DB client name? Mysql?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails best way to get previous and next active record object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665804/rails-best-way-to-get-previous-and-next-active-record-object), which I incidentally answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@more_posts = @comment.posts.where(id: [@post.id + 1, @post.id + 2])
```

or

```
@more_posts = @comment.posts.where("id > ?", @post.id).limit(2)
```

If you are ordering by position consider:

```
@more_posts = @comment.posts.order(position: :asc).where("position > ?", @post.position).limit(2)
```

Comment: Neither seem to work and return nothing. Since I'm ordering by position and not id I switched those like so: @comment.posts.where("position > ?", @post.position).limit(2)