# Efficiently writing a large mysql2 result to CSV

Tags: mysql, ruby

We're building a CSV export mechanism in a CMS we just built and we're having trouble keeping memory down on result sets with millions of rows. What is the best way to write a 1MM+ row result from MySQL (via the `mysql2` gem) to CSV. If it makes any difference, we're on Ruby 1.9.3p194 and MySQL 5.5. Our main goal is to keep memory consumption down on the Ruby process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default mysql2 caches the ruby objects that it creates for its result set. If you turn this off then memory consumption should be greatly reduced. for example you might do

```
require 'mysql2'
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "someuser")
client.query 'use some_db'

CSV.open('output.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  results = client.query("SELECT * FROM big_table")
  results.each(:cache_rows => false) do |row| 
    csv << [row['column_a'], row['column_b']]
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm already passing stream: true when executing the command which according to the docs ignores cache_rows setting as streaming should force it to not cache rows.. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: are you using master? the version currently on ruby gems (0.3.11) predates the :stream option.

Comment: Ah, we are not using master. Thanks for bringing this to my attention!

Answer (score 4):

[`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html) or [*`mysqldump`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html).

Comment: Yes, this is the best solution.  Look at the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` field.  It's tab separated by default so you'll have to set it to ','.   Also, you can only write to the server's file system. Could be a deal breaker if you need to do this remotely. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html

Comment: Good to know this option exists, unfortunately it won't work in my current application as I have to do a little bit of processing on each result row before appending it to the CSV.

Comment: @giantcola: What sort of processing?  Can it not be done in SQL?

Comment: @eggyal I have to run some of the SQL values through app-level logic before exporting to make the resulting CSV more human/excel-friendly. While it may be possible to run most if not all of the processing in SQL, I'd rather not tie my business logic into my query like that.

Comment: @giantcola: Understood.  Your reasoning is very sound.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use eggyal's `OUTFILE` solution for some reason I would split the query into batches using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`:

```
SELECT ... LIMIT 5000 OFFSET 5000
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

The memory consumption will come from creating a large single ruby array from the big 1M+ query. By splitting it into smaller batches and dumping each batch in turn into the CSV file will help keep memory consumption lower.

Comment: It'd be pretty hard work on MySQL to scan the results in order to find each offset.  Better to filter the data in batches based on some indexed column.

Comment: @eggyal - Ok. Thanks. Wasn't aware of the performance penalty. I also found this while researching further about the performance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481388/why-does-mysql-higher-limit-offset-slow-the-query-down . Anyway it seems like `OUTFILE` will be much easier and faster.