# Will a large offset trigger millions of reads in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, profiling

I have a system that needs to suck up an entire MS SQL database. Currently it does so with something like:

```
select top 1000 from table where id > 0 order by id;
```

Then, for the next chunk:

```
select top 1000 from table where id > 1000 order by id;
```

And then:

```
select top 1000 from table where id > 2000 order by id;
```

And so forth.

In MySQL, I've learned that doing `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` queries [is brutally slow because the database has to first sort the results, then scan over the `OFFSET` count](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4502426/64911). When that count gets big, life starts to suck as the read count skyrockets.

My question is this: does the same problem apply to `TOP`? Put another way, can I expect a really high read count when I run these queries on a database with, say 10,000,000 records, at the time when `id > 9,999,000`? If so, are there any ways to handle this better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be very fast if ID is indexed.  If that column is not indexed then it would case a full table scan.

I would suggest the following in addition:

```
  select * from table where id > 0 and id <= 1000 order by id ;
```

This way if you don't have all records you don't have bugs (duplicates).

Comment: It won't cause an index scan of 9,999,000 rows for the last chunk? I think that's part of my worry. I'm pretty sure MySQL **would** do that.

Comment: @mlissner this is the question I answered.  If the column id has an index then it will not.  This is fundamental to the way SQL Server works.