# Need a linq to generate itself join

Tags: linq, join

According to this post [Why does MYSQL higher LIMIT offset slow the query down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481388/why-does-mysql-higher-limit-offset-slow-the-query-down) and this article http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/ I need a linq to create below query

```
SELECT  news.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    news
        WHERE   cat_id= x
        ORDER BY
                id DESC
        LIMIT m, n
        ) o
JOIN    news
ON      news.id = o.id
```

Comment: @JonSkeet please refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481388/why-does-mysql-higher-limit-offset-slow-the-query-down

Comment: That post explains why you want to do this, it doesn't explain what you have tried, or what happened.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. (Skip/Take equals the Limit)

```
from u in news
join n in
(
    from x in news
    where x.cat_id = 10
    orderby x.Id descending
    select x
).Skip(10).Take(20) on u.Id equals n.Id
select u
```

Comment: This linq does not genereate my query. also the result of it is not same as my query

Comment: Can only test against SQL server 2008 and it generates the correct code. So what does it generate with your provider?

Comment: The below query generate in MySQL:  SELECT
`Extent1`.`Id`, 
...
FROM `news` AS `Extent1` INNER JOIN (SELECT
`Extent2`.`Id`, 
...
FROM `news` AS `Extent2`
 ORDER BY 
`Extent2`.`Id` DESC LIMIT 10,20) AS `Limit1` ON `Extent1`.`Id` = `Limit1`.`Id`

Comment: How is that different from what you wanted? The `cat_id`? Just add it to the inner query

Comment: @GhootiFarangi please be more specific.