# How can I generate this special query by LINQ?

Tags: mysql, linq, join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need a linq to generate itself join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579917/need-a-linq-to-generate-itself-join)

According to this post [Why does MYSQL higher LIMIT offset slow the query down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481388/why-does-mysql-higher-limit-offset-slow-the-query-down) and this article http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/ I need a linq to create below query

```
SELECT  news.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    news
        WHERE   cat_id= x
        ORDER BY
                id DESC
        LIMIT m, n
        ) o
JOIN    news
ON      news.id = o.id
```

Comment: Why cant you just "select * from news where cat__id = x order by id desc limit m,n" .. why the double query?

Comment: @BugFinder Please read this article http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/

Comment: Cant view from work :p - hence commenting on what I can see

Comment: Never just repeat a question please! Improve the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried...

```
var res =
    from item in 
        (from newsItem in news
        where newsItem.cat_id = x
        select newsItem.id).Skip(m).Take(n)

    join other in news
    on other.id equals item.id

    select item
```