# Pagination with SQLite using LIMIT

Tags: sql, sqlite, limit

I'm writing my own SQLIteBrowser and I have one final problem, which apparently is quite often discussed on the web, but it doesn't seem to have a good general solution.

So currently I store the SQL which the user entered. Whenever I need to fetch rows, I execute the SQL by adding "Limit n, m` at the end of the SQL.

For normal SQLs, which I mostly use, this seems good enough. However if I want to use limit myself in the query, this will obviously give an error, because the resulting sql can look like this:

```
 select * from table limit 30 limit 1,100
```

which is obviously wrong. Is there some better way to do this?

My idea was, that I could scan the SQL and check if there is a limit clause already used and then ignore it. Of course it's not as simlpe as that, because if I have an sql like this:

```
 select * from a where a.b = ( select x from z limit 1)
```

it obviously should still apply my limit in such a case, so I could scan the string from the end and look if there is a limit somehwere. My question now is, how feasable this is. As I don't know who the SQL parser works, I'm not sure if LIMIT has to be at the end of SQL or if there can be other commands at the end as well.

I tested it with `order by`and `group by` and I get SQL errors if `limit` is not at the end, so my assumption seems to be true.

Comment: Doesn't `LIMIT n,m` work in sqlite ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325515/sqlite-limit-offset-query-doubt?rq=1

Comment: Of course it works. I'm using it after all. The question is if it must always be at the end of an SQL, as I'm writing a browser and I don't know which kind of queries

Comment: Seems I found a solution. I simply wrap the whole SQL into `select * from (UserSQL) limit n, m` So far I hav not found any problem with that.

Comment: Oh, maybe you just want to vary `n, m` based on current user selection (most probably the "current page"). Is that right ?

Comment: @MarcelloRomani, The user can enter an arbitrary sql which I watnt o execute. Since I don't want to load all records at once I wrap it in a limit and retrieve only N rows. Whenever the user scrolls down and reaches the bottom, I fetch additional n rows, until the select delivers no more. So it acts as a page of size N.

Comment: This is quite different from the original question. I suggest you edit it to include this text, which is a lot clearer IMHO. A good title could be "Pagination of arbitrary SQL query". My 2 cents :)

Comment: @MarcelloRomani, the solution I found made the question a bit obsolet. However I found a lot of questions regarding pagination, using limit, so I think it might help somebody if he wants to implement a similar approach. I can also delete the question, as I already found a solution.

Comment: My understanding is the established practice is to answer your own question. That way you'd still have a problem with a solution, which could benefit others in future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found now a much better solution which is quite simple and doesn't require me to parse the SQL.

The user can enter an arbitrary sql. The result is loaded into a table. Since we don't want to load the whole result at once, as this can return millions of records, only N records are retriueved. When the user scroll to the bottom of the table the next N items are fetched and loaded into the table.

The solution is, to wrapt the SQL into an outer sql with my page size limits.

```
 select * from (arbitrary UserSQL) limit PageSize, CurrentOffset
```

I tested it with SQLs I regularly use, and this seem to work quite nicely and is also fast enough for my purpose.

However, I don't know wether SQLite has a mechanism to fetch the new rows faster, or if the sql has to be rerun every time. In that case it might not be a good solution fo rrealy complex queries with a long response time.

Comment: According to the following SO article, limit X, Y has the database actually reading everything up until Y, then stripping everything before X, which makes this very inefficient. Better to store some value from a column, like timestamp or id: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468586/efficient-paging-in-sqlite-with-millions-of-records

Comment: There is no way around that, unless you know what you are searching for and can limit it in a better way. That's the nature of SQL databases and also the same with other vendors (like i.e. Oracle)

Comment: But OP does know what he's looking for, at least that's what I interpret when he writes "select * from a where a.b" as an example.

Comment: [Efficient paging in SQLite with millions of records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468586/efficient-paging-in-sqlite-with-millions-of-records/14468878)