# paging in sqlite table using c#

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to page through this table so I ended up with this query (which is not working).

```
SELECT MIN(user_uid) AS FIRST,
MAX(user_uid) AS LAST,
user_number, user_name
FROM user_table
WHERE user_uid > MAX(FIRST,{0}) AND user_uid < MIN(LAST,{1})
AND ( user_name LIKE '%{2}%' OR user_number LIKE '%{3}%' )
AND user_category={4} OR user_category={5}
ORDER BY user_uid LIMIT {6}
```

I'm getting parameters' values from my c# variables. I'm storing FIRST, LAST externally to use them for moving to next/previous pages.

I created this index too:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON user_table (user_uid);
```

**please note:** I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468586/efficient-paging-in-sqlite-with-millions-of-records), but this is the only way I thought about to get First and Last values.

How to page in this table efficiently?

Comment: This query does not make sense. What values do you intend to use for `{0}` and `{1}` on the first page, and on the next page?

Comment: 0 and a value to denote max int value

Comment: The first and last value are the values in the first and last returned row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query isn't working because `Min(Column)` and `Max(Column)` in SQL returns an evaluation (aggregate) of all rows so doesn't know what value to have for every row in the non-aggregate query in your question.

If you really need the min and max you could return them in separate select statements so your dataset has 3 tables (if you're using ADO).

However paging should generally be achieved [using offset](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_limit_clause.htm) as in the case below (note that the order by should make the query deterministic so it returns the same results every time).

```
SELECT
user_number, 
user_name
FROM user_table
WHERE ( user_name LIKE '%{1}%' OR user_number LIKE '%{2}%' )
AND user_category={3} OR user_category={4}
ORDER BY user_uid LIMIT {5} OFFSET {6}
```

Where `{5}` is page size and `{6}` is `page number * page size`.

Sorry if this doesn't answer your question, it's not clear what you want FIRST and LAST for. Page number and size are generally kept track off by the UI. Additionally, I haven't tested the above in SQLite.

#### Note

The code you've posted above looks vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) if you're using something like `String.Format()` to build your query. Consider changing this.