# Any Express + SQLite Pagination plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, sqlite

I've been looking for (on npm) pagination plugins for SQLite and Express, since I have an app that lists items using those plugins, but I did not find anything. If someone knows any express plugin that works with SQLite, I appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, SO is not an advice forum. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: Pagination doesn't require a particular library, you just use offsets and limits in your database queries.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new user at SO. I promise to read in my spare time the SO.Policies

Answer (score 4):

Pagination doesn't require a particular library, you just use offsets and limits in your database queries.

```
SELECT * FROM items LIMIT 25
```

The above query will only get the first 25 records from the `items` table.

```
SELECT * FROM items OFFSET 50 LIMIT 25
```

The above query will start at the 50th record, then get 25 more records after that.

That is the basis for all pagination. You supply an offset usually `pageNumber * pageSize` and a limit `pageSize`.

Comment: OK, I'll try it. I was confused because there are many Pagination's libraries for express on npm (where I usually look for improved solutions, and avoid "reinventing the wheel")
Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: If that's the case, you should pick one, try to get it working and then come back here if you run into any issues. Recommending libraries is heavily opinion-based and the suggestions can quickly go out of date.

Comment: This might [become inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468586/efficient-paging-in-sqlite-with-millions-of-records).

Comment: @CL. it's the standard way of doing pagination so UNTIL it becomes inefficient, it isn't a problem. Don't prematurely optimize if you don't have to.