# How to use Paging with SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, paging

I want to integrate [Paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) with SQLite in existing application. There are around 90 tables in my database so its time consuming to convert to [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/). I also tried `LIMIT...OFFSET` but that takes time to process data every time.

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to post what you have tried in order to get help. Currently your question is to broad.

Comment: Hi @HB. Thanks for interest. I just want to know how to integrate `Paging` with `SQLite`. I seen many sites and stack overflow questions but can't get tutorial for `SQLite`. There are some demos for `Room` DB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient paging in SQLite with millions of records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468586/efficient-paging-in-sqlite-with-millions-of-records)