# Cannot read 1 table in .sqlite but able to read another table

Tags: python, sqlite, pyspark, jupyter-lab

I had a database in sqlite file with 2 tables inside it and size around 6GB. Let's say table customers & table services

```
CREATE TABLE customers (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
name TEXT, phone TEXT, male INTEGER NOT NULL, nationality TEXT NOT NULL) 
CREATE TABLE services ("id" TEXT, "date" DATE, "service_details" TEXT)
```

I can read both tables with DB browser (SQLite) and able to export both tables into .csv files without issues as well. Table customers will be around 900MB and services around 2.3GB.

Then I'll load both tables into pyspark dataframe via Jupyter Lab with the following codes:

```
sqlite_jdbc = r"sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.3.jar"
sqlite_file = r"mydb.sqlite"

spark = SparkSession.builder\
                .config("spark.jars", sqlite_jdbc)\
                .master("local")\
                .appName("PySpark_SQLite")\
                .getOrCreate()
customers = spark.read.format('jdbc')\
            .options(url=r'jdbc:sqlite:{}'.format(myvas_file), 
                     dbtable='customers', 
                     driver='org.sqlite.JDBC').load()
services = spark.read.format('jdbc')\
            .options(url=r'jdbc:sqlite:{}'.format(myvas_file), 
                     dbtable='services', 
                     driver='org.sqlite.JDBC').load()
```

Both tables were able to read without error. But with code

```
customers.show(2)
```

The dataFrame was able to show in jupyter lab as below =

```
+---+----+-----+----+-----------+
|id |name|phone|male|nationality|
+---+----+-----+----+-----------+
|1  |ABC |0000 |1   |MY         |
|2  |BCD |0100 |0   |IND        |
+---+----+-----+----+-----------+
```

However, when I get error while trying to run the following code =

```
services.show()
```

The error code as below =

```
    ~\Downloads\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    492 
    493         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 494             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    495         else:
    496             try:

~\Downloads\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1307 
   1308         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1309         return_value = get_return_value(
   1310             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1311 

~\Downloads\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    109     def deco(*a, **kw):
    110         try:
--> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
    112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~\Downloads\Anaconda3\envs\holoviz\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o39.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) (PC-WEIHONG.phcorp.local executor driver): java.sql.SQLException: Error parsing date
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getDate(JDBC3ResultSet.java:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$makeGetter$2(JdbcUtils.scala:385)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$makeGetter$2$adapted(JdbcUtils.scala:383)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:352)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2021-10-21" does not match (\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q \E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q.\E(\p{Nd}++)
    at org.sqlite.date.FastDateParser.parse(FastDateParser.java:300)
    at org.sqlite.date.FastDateFormat.parse(FastDateFormat.java:490)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getDate(JDBC3ResultSet.java:290)
    ... 24 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2258)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2207)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2445)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2387)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2376)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2196)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2217)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:472)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:425)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3696)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2722)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3687)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3685)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2722)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2929)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:338)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error parsing date
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getDate(JDBC3ResultSet.java:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$makeGetter$2(JdbcUtils.scala:385)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$makeGetter$2$adapted(JdbcUtils.scala:383)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:352)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2021-10-21" does not match (\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q \E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q.\E(\p{Nd}++)
    at org.sqlite.date.FastDateParser.parse(FastDateParser.java:300)
    at org.sqlite.date.FastDateFormat.parse(FastDateFormat.java:490)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getDate(JDBC3ResultSet.java:290)
    ... 24 more
```

I can read both table and extract to csv file with DB Browser (SQLite) and read both csv file into pyspark and both table also be able to use .show() without error. However, due to daily update of the .sqlite file, I would like to read both tables with pyspark directly. Would be much appreciate if anybody can help to tackle this issue. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Did you try use sqlite3 to access the db? https://docs.python.org/es/3.10/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Thanks. It can be read with sqlite3 and both tables can be shown, but in view of the size of the database, my ram will be overwhelming (RAM only 8GB, running Windows 11) if I extract all the data out.

Comment: You can page your requests, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14468878/3969110 and https://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ScrollingCursor