# Make SELECT with LIMIT and OFFSET on big table fast

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

I have more than 10 million records in a table.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY datecol DESC
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 999990
```

Output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on [explain.depesz.com](http://explain.depesz.com/s/9iee).
Executing the above query takes about 10 seconds. How can I make this faster?

#### Update

The execution time is reduced half by using a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl where id in 
(SELECT id FROM tbl ORDER BY datecol DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 999990)
```

Output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on [explain.depesz.com](http://explain.depesz.com/s/ibV).

Comment: Is there an index on `DATECOLUMN`? Is the high offset just an example of pagination, or could you do this the other way around?

Comment: no their is no index on DATECOLUMN, i am using this query for grid, so i need pagination..  What's the other way.?

Comment: Put an index on the column.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/indexes-intro.html

Comment: hi i have create index, but no use..!!!!

Comment: Add the definition of the table and the explain plan for the query to the question please.

Comment: After the creation of the index do command an `analyze mytable`.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info in particular the advice on details needed.

Comment: this is my query plan http://explain.depesz.com/s/9iee

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481388/why-does-mysql-higher-limit-offset-slow-the-query-down  MySQL and Postgresql are very similar on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an index on the column used in `ORDER BY`. Ideally in the same sort order, but PostgreSQL can scan indexes backwards at almost the same speed.

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_datecol_idx ON tbl (datecol DESC);
```

More [about indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes.html) and [`CREATE INDEX`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createindex.html) in the current manual.
Test with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) to get actual times in addition to the query plan.

Of course all [the usual advice for performance optimization](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization) applies, too.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar my self with a very large table ( >100m records ) and found that using Offset / Limit was killing performance. 
Offset for the first 10m records was (with limit 1) about 1.5 minutes to retrieve with it growing exponentially.
By record 50m I was up to 3 minutes per select - even using sub-queries.

I came across a post [here which details useful alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307991/postgres-why-is-the-performance-so-bad-on-subselects-with-offset-limit?noredirect=1&lq=1).

I modified this slightly to suit my needs and came up with a method that gave me pretty quick results.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE 
just_index AS SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER (ORDER BY [VALUE-You-need]), [VALUE-You-need] 
FROM [your-table-name];
```

This was a once-off - took about 4 minutes but I then had all values I wanted
Next was to create a function that would loop at the "Offset" I needed:

```
create or replace
function GetOffsets () 
returns void as $$ 
declare 
-- For this part of the function I only wanted values after 90 million up to 120 million
counter bigint := 90000000;
maxRows bigInt := 120000000;
begin
drop table if exists OffsetValues;
create temp table OffsetValues
(
    offset_myValue bigint
);

while counter <= maxRows loop 
    insert into OffsetValues(offset_myValue)
    select [VALUE-You-need] from just_index where row_number > counter
    limit 1;

    -- here I'm looping every 500,000 records - this is my 'Offset'
    counter := counter + 500000 ;
end loop ;
end ;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then run the function:

```
select GetOffsets();
```

Again, a once-off amount of time (I went from ~3 minutes getting one of my offset values to 3 milliseconds to get one of my offset values).
Then select from the temp-table:

```
select * from OffsetValues;
```

This worked really well for me in terms of performance - I don't think i'll be using offset going forward if I can help it.

Hope this improves performance for any of your larger tables.