# PostgREST using limit and offset in subqueries or CTE

Tags: postgresql, postgrest

we are using PostgREST in our project for some quite complex database views.

From some point on, when we are using limit and offset (x-range headers or query parameters) with sub-selects we get very high response times.

From what we have read, it seems like this is a known issue where postgresql executes the sub-selects even for the records which are not requested. The solution would be to jiggle a little with the offset and limit, putting it in a subselect or a CTE table.

Is there an internal GUC value or something similar that we can use in the database views in order to optimize the response times ? Does anybody have a hint on how to achieve this ?

**EDIT:** as suggested here are some more details. Let's say we have a relationship between product and parts. I want to know the parts count per product (this is a simplified version of the database views that we are exposing).

There are two ways of doing this

**A. Subselect:**

```
    SELECT products.id
            ,(
                    SELECT count(part_id) AS total
                    FROM parts
                    WHERE product_id = products.id
                    )
    FROM products limit 1000 OFFSET 99000
```

**B. CTE:**

```
    WITH parts_count
    AS (
            SELECT product_id
                    ,count(part_id) AS total
            FROM parts
            GROUP BY product_id
            ORDER BY product_id
            )
    SELECT products.id
            ,parts_count.total
    FROM products
    LEFT JOIN parts_count ON parts_count.product_id = product.id 
    LIMIT 1000     
    OFFSET 99000
```

Problem with **A** is that the sub-select is performed for every row so even though I read only 1000 records there are 100 000 subselects.

Problem with **B** is that the join with parts_count table takes very long since there are 100 0000 records there (although the with query takes only 200 ms! for 2000 records). Ideally I would like to limit the parts_count table with the same limit and offset as the main query but I can't do this in PostgREST since it just appends the limit and offset at the end, I don't have access to those parameters inside the **WITH** query

Answer (score 4):

It is unavoidable that high `OFFSET` leads to bad performance.

There is no other way to compute `OFFSET` but to scan and discard all the rows until you reach the offset, and no database in the world will be fast if `OFFSET` is high.

That's a conceptual problem, and the only way to avoid it is to avoid `OFFSET`.

If your goal is pagination, then usually [keyset pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) is a better solution:

You add an `ORDER BY` clause that matches your requirements, make sure there is a unique key in the `ORDER BY` clause and remember the last value you found. To fetch the next page, add a `WHERE` condition with that values. With proper index support, this can be very fast.

For your query, a more efficient version is probably:

```
SELECT p.id
       count(parts.part_id) AS total
FROM (SELECT id FROM products
      LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 99000) p
   LEFT JOIN parts ON parts.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id;
```

It is rather weird that you have no `ORDER BY`, but `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The offset of the main query is not so much of a problem here, what is causing the performance loss is the sub-selects. I did a test where I used a CTE with the same offset as the main query and joined it with the main query afterwards, and the performance was acceptable. So I am trying to intercept the pagination of the outer query in the subselect. Something like the accepted answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307991/postgres-why-is-the-performance-so-bad-on-subselects-with-offset-limit

Comment: Ok. If you need more information, you'll have to add more details to your question.

Comment: I have updated the original question with more details

Comment: I have added an improved query to the answer.

Comment: This is just a simplified version of my query, I have an order by in the original. I am a little dubious it will work since like I said PostgREST just add the `limit` and `offset` at the end of the query but I will try it tomorrow and let you know how it works.

Comment: A framework that does not allow you to use custom SQL is lame.