# MYSQL higher LIMIT offset slow the query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit, mysql-slow-query-log

I have the following Mysql query. It is a slow query and will take around 3 seconds to finish. message_id is the primary key. The problem of this is the high LIMIT offset `LIMIT 85075, 25`.

```
SELECT * FROM `phorum_messages` WHERE 1  and `catergory` >=0 and parent_id=0   order by `message_id` desc  LIMIT 85075, 25;
```

Based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481388/why-does-mysql-higher-limit-offset-slow-the-query-down), I changed query to the following way. The problem is if I remove `where parent_id=0`, the speed is much faster. But I really need `where parent_id=0`

**EDIT: I already created index for parent_id and message_id.**

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  message_id
        FROM    phorum_messages where parent_id=0
        ORDER BY message_id desc LIMIT 85075, 25
        ) q
JOIN    phorum_messages t
ON      t.message_id = q.message_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an index on your parent_id column to speed up the query process

```
CREATE INDEX indexName ON phorum_messages (parent_id);
```

Comment: YES MORE INDEXES, i didnt think they mattered until it cut my outer join calls from 10 minutes to < 1 second.

Comment: `parent_id` and `message_id` should be in the same index I think, because they are both used in this query. But I am not that good at databases.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I already created index for parent_id

Comment: you should also index in category to optimize for this query

Comment: @Sop but with which fields, your index can contain multiple fields. YOu should index category and parent_id together and message_id and stated above

Comment: @j_mcnally, yes, i already created index for parent_id and message_id.

Comment: @Sop oh, if you've already indexes... one time i was surprised by a thing that I found not so logic... But more performant. You could try to replace "ON t.message_id = q.message_id" by "ON t.message_id IN q.message_id"... Let us know if it's more performant to you :)

Comment: @pouki06, if I changed to that way, i got query error report.

Comment: @Sop OK, maybe the join cause the error, i tried this trick in a WHERE condition... Sry !

Answer (score 0):

DO you have an index on parent_id or category_id? It doing a full table scan as you have no indexes on the search fields. 
The queries with limit takes almost same amount of time except for sending data back(which comes after execution phase).

Answer (score 0):

When using large LIMIT offsets it is sometimes good to use a different approach that doesn't use a LIMIT offset.

For the first query use

```
SELECT * FROM `phorum_messages`
WHERE `catergory` >=0 and parent_id=0 
order by `message_id` desc 
LIMIT 25
```

and save the lowest message_id as $min_id

next_call:
Then you can call

```
SELECT * FROM `phorum_messages`
WHERE `catergory` >=0 and parent_id=0  AND message_id < $min_id
order by `message_id` desc 
LIMIT 25
```

to get the next 25 results. Set $min_id to the minimum message_id that you got from the result set. goto next_call.

Comment: Thanks Michael, it is a solution for this question. I'm not sure is there any other answer.

Comment: I'm using this query for separate pages for forum messages. It is not possible for me to create page NO. 789 without knowing the message_id. Your approach need to create all pages subsequently

Answer (score 0):

Create a composite index on `(parent_id, message_id)` and rewrite your query a little:

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  message_id
        FROM    phorum_messages
        WHERE   parent_id = 0
        ORDER BY
                parent_id DESC, message_id DESC
        LIMIT   85075, 25
        ) q
JOIN    phorum_messages t
ON      t.message_id = q.message_id
```

Comment: I tried in Phpmyadmin, 'Showing rows 0 - 24 ( 25 total, Query took 1.1760 sec)' It seems still not fast. I created a composite index on parent_id, message_id

Comment: @Sop: you can't make it instant, not with large `OFFSET + LIMIT`. Please post the query plan.

Comment: I forgot to mention I have total 204,407 rows in phorum_messages table.

Comment: `id
select_type
table
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
Extra
1
PRIMARY
<derived2>
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
25
1
PRIMARY
t
eq_ref
PRIMARY,message_id
PRIMARY
4
q.message_id
1
2
DERIVED
phorum_messages
ALL
parent_id,parent_id_2
parent_id_2
4
204408
Using filesort
`

Comment: I don't know how to post query plan.