# why use django haystack slice queryset too slow?

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, whoosh

I use whoosh as the search backend.

when I get just 3 search result, code:

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python
> # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
> import sys
> sys.path.append('/home/guomeng/projects/tapplex_ringtones')
> import os
> os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "tapplex_ringtones.settings"
>
> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
> from ringtones.models import Ringtone
> import time
>
> query_word = u'sky'
> t0 = time.time()
> sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(Ringtone).filter(content=query_word)[:3]
> t1 = time.time()
> print sqs
> print t1 - t0
> ```

the result is:

```
[<SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'1730')>, <SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'28959')>, <SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'25889')>]
0.422543048859> 0.422543048859
```

when I get all search result, code:

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python
> # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
> import sys
> sys.path.append('/home/guomeng/projects/tapplex_ringtones')
> import os
> os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "tapplex_ringtones.settings"
>
> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
> from ringtones.models import Ringtone
> import time
>
> query_word = u'sky'
> t0 = time.time()
> sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(Ringtone).filter(content=query_word)
> t1 = time.time()
> print sqs
> print t1 - t0
> ```

the result is:

```
[<SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'1730')>, <SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'28959')>, <SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'25889')>, <SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'5303')>, <SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'5335')>, <SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'5411')>, <SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'1212')>, <SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'28473')>, <SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'23867')>, <SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'27087')>, <SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'26849')>, <SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'2973')>, <SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'2645')>, <SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'31007')>, <SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'11637')>, <SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'16957')>, <SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'106')>, <SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'2481')>, <SearchResult: ringtones.ringtone (pk=u'15697')>]
0.19460105896
```

why I get all the result is fast?

Comment: I am not familiar with haystack, but try use `from timeit import default_timer as timer` `start = timer()` `end = timer()` `print(end-start)` and print query, not result `print(sqs.query)` and post query here

Comment: and actually if you print both query - you will see that in the second case Django add `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481388/why-does-mysql-higher-limit-offset-slow-the-query-down

Answer (score 0):

Probably because:

```
SearchQuerySet().models(Ringtone).filter(content=query_word)[:3]
```

Does everything that

```
SearchQuerySet().models(Ringtone).filter(content=query_word)
```

does, but also, updates the query set with a limit clause and returns a new queryset. This could account for all or some of the time difference. To get meaningful results you'd need to average the time taken over many calls, and analyze some of the internal code - i.e. how long does the DB take to process the query, and what actually is the query etc.