# How to add big offset?

Tags: mysql, sql, datatables

I've run this two queries using mysql work bench:

1. `SELECT bussId FROM tempBusiness order by bussId ASC limit 250000 ,1`
2. `SELECT bussId FROM tempBusiness order by bussId ASC limit 1 ,1`

The first one doesn't finish running, the second one returns the bussId very fast (0.096 sec / 0.000016 sec).

Here is the explain for the above two queries:

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

What may be the problem ?

Comment: @popovitsj no ! it shouldn't return 250000 row, it should return one row but the offset is 250000 !

Comment: Thats usual since when you limit data from a big number the optimizer probably will do a full table scan, however this could be achieved in another way using range filter on an indexed column something as  `SELECT bussId FROM tempBusiness where bussId >250000 order by bussId limit 1 `

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty . . . The optimizer should really be doing a full *index*  scan, not a full *table* scan.  That appears to be what it is doing.

Comment: @david that's what I said. But I guess there shouldn't be a difference in that respect between the two queries, so I don't think that it has to do anything with memory on second thought.

Comment: @popovitsj for smaller number it's working , but why when the number big , it take  a long of time to return the result , I try with other table and it's return the one result fast .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does MYSQL higher LIMIT offset slow the query down?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481388/why-does-mysql-higher-limit-offset-slow-the-query-down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get to an offset of `N` in an indexed column, it has to scan through the index sequentially. If the offset is small, this finishes quickly. But to get to a very large index like `250000`, it has to load many entries from the index into memory.

I don't think there's any good way to optimize this. If you have sequential ID fields, you could use `WHERE id = 250000` instead of using `LIMIT`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but why when i try the same query but with different table name in another table , mysql return one result very fast .

Comment: which index, are you referring to the primary key ?

Comment: Yes, the primary key is an index. `EXPLAIN` says it's using the index.

Comment: so maybe at tempBusiness table , the index didn't finish loading yet ?

Comment: Right. What happens if you try two queries in a row with large offsets?

Comment: if the query at tempBusiness table it will not finish running, but if it at another table it return the result very fast !

Comment: but How to check if my index doesn't finish loading ?

Comment: There's no way to check. It loads indexes as it needs them.

Comment: so if I create an index, may it be created after one month , when mysql want to use a query that will use that index ?

Comment: The index is created immediately. It's just not loaded into RAM until it's needed.

Comment: aaa so, if I insert row into tempBusiness, I will enforce mysql to use the primary key index, so if I run again query number one, mysql will use the index (because it already at the memory) then it will return the result fast ! right ?

Comment: I don't think so. Adding to the index doesn't require loading the whole thing into memory.

Comment: thank you but my final question : should my sql load the index into the ram to use it, I mean it can't use the index if it not loaded into the ram ?

Comment: The only way that computers can use data is to load it into memory. That's how computers work.

Comment: but where it's stored , it's not stored into the memory ?

Comment: No, it's stored on disk.

Comment: aaa ok thank you very much for you help, so now i will search the difference between disk and memory (ram) !

Comment: How can a computer programmer not know the difference between disk and RAM? Disk is where you have named files. RAM is where the variables in your programs are.