# speed up LIMIT query with millions of records

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have 8 millions of records in table and this query is just too slow. It's for sitemap (that we need to index it all). In this example I choose 1000 items from position 6 millions.

```
SELECT source, identifier
FROM mh_download
WHERE deleted =0
LIMIT 6000000 , 1000
```

33 seconds

Table is MyISAM and column deleted has index. MySQL version 5.5.41.

Comment: Without order by your LIMIT will return indeterminate results.So why start at 600.000 then?Try adding ORDER BY either source or identifier before LIMIT,depending on which one has an index

Comment: I need go throw all records in table. If you know better option, please tell me. (also thanks for edit)

Comment: You can find some interesting reading material on the MySQL site on this topic: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found duplicate
[Why does MYSQL higher LIMIT offset slow the query down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481388/why-does-mysql-higher-limit-offset-slow-the-query-down?lq=1)

so best solution will be

```
1)Hold the last id of a set of data(30) (e.g. lastId = 530)
2)Add the condition "WHERE id > lastId limit 0,30"
```

Thank you all for your patience

Comment: Further discussion in my [Pagination blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).