# Mysql subquery long work

Tags: mysql

I have next mysql query

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dom_small WHERE count>=0 AND dom NOT IN 
(SELECT dom FROM dom_small WHERE was_blocked=1) 
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 4702020
```

When i increase OFFSET more and more, subquery run long and long.

When OFFSET 0 mysql query load 0 sec but when 4702020 mysql query load 1 min 19,49 sec

How to solve this problem?

Comment: usually higher offset slows down performance.

Comment: Thinks about it, it has to select all and then sort all and then seek forward `4702020` rows and then deliver you 30 rows from there. Of course it runs longer when you increase the offset

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481388/why-does-mysql-higher-limit-offset-slow-the-query-down

Answer (score 0):

You can yield same result with out using subquery

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dom_small WHERE count>=0 AND  was_blocked=1
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 4702020;
```

Comment: I think @Dmitriy Kupriyanov wants result which is not in was_blocked=1. So your answer in incorrect.

Comment: Think right, but in this case i get the equal time for all query when offset 0 or 4702020. Approximately 7 secons. It is cause why i use subquery.

Comment: equal time with incorrect results is still failure.  If dom "A" has 25 entries and  1 of them is marked as blocked, then the user does not want to see dom "A" at all regardless of the 24 that actually were not originally blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Use following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dom_small WHERE count>=0 AND dom NOT IN 
  (select * from(SELECT dom FROM dom_small WHERE was_blocked=1) t1 ) 
  ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 4702020
```

It can speed up the performance by caching the sub-query result. I previously used this method and it helped me much.

But as others mentioned using offset with big numbers slow down the performance.

Comment: Thank for you idea but 30 rows in set (2 min 5,96 sec)

Comment: @DmitriyKupriyanov thus I think optimizing the sub-query can not improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dom_small WHERE count>=0 AND dom NOT IN 
(SELECT dom FROM dom_small WHERE was_blocked=1) 
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 4702020

Although the other comments are accurate, the only suggestion I can offer is that your distinct and subquery are from the same table "dom_small".  Also, you are not doing any aggregate count(*) vs what appears to be an actual column in your table called count.

That said, I would have an index to help optimize the query on

```
( dom, was_blocked, count )
```