# Large result (500000 item) query ending before done looping through

Tags: php, mysql, linux, memory

I have a large result set returned in my query.  For some reason, when I loop through the results, doing what I need with each row, I'm finding that the script is ending early.

```
$stmt1 = $mysqli1->prepare("select distinct p.tn, n.model, n.software_version , c.card_part_num                             
                            from N_DB.DSLAMS n                              
                            join N_DB.dslam_card on n.nodealias = c.nodealias
                            join N_DB.dslam_port p on c.index = p.dslam_card_index                      
                            WHERE ping_reply = '1'
                            order by p.tn
                            LIMIT 60000000"); 
    //it's less than 60 million, but I set that limit to make sure my issue wasn't that I was setting the limit too low

if(!$stmt1->bind_result($num, $model, $software_version, $card)) 
{
    echo "Binding results failed: (" . $stmt1->errno . ") " . $stmt1->error;
}   
print "will query depo next \n";
if(!$stmt1->execute())
{ 
    $tempErr = "Error querying depo db: " . $stmt1->error;
    printf($tempErr . "\n");    //show mysql execute error if exists  
    $err->logThis($tempErr);
} 
print "done querying depo \n";
$total_records = $stmt1->num_rows();   
print "Total records to process: ".$total_records." \n"; //says 0, but it clearly has many
 // when it loops thru them, 
 //printing things
  print " Please wait. \n";

  $count = 0;

  while($stmt1->fetch()) {

      $count ++;
      if (($count % 50000) == 0){
          print "Working on record ".$count." \n"; //I never see this before it prints done
      }
      //do other things that are more interesting
  }//while
  print "\n done looping through tn's "; //it gets to this too soon
```

I think I'm processing too many records, but there isn't a logical way to cut the results to be less than 500000, so the only solution is to divide up the results.  I've been looking at  [taking forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680738/mysql-query-with-limit-and-large-offset-taking-forever), and [limit..peppy comments](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/problem-selecting-300-000-rows-from-mysql-database/40126/18).  I'd like to divide up the results, but I'm having trouble understanding what these people are doing.

How would I divide up my results into chunks so I don't, presumably, run out of memory.  I'm relatively new to MySQL, so I apologize if I'm a little green.

Oh, and I checked max_execution_time => 0 => 0 , so that looks fine.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: `ini_set('output_buffering',0)` to get prints before end of file. use `flush()` after print. or `ini_set('implicit_flush',1)` instead of `flush()`

Comment: I'm seeing Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query' in /opt/IBM/custom/NAC_Dslam/compare.php:161

Comment: If I'm losing connection to the mysql server, would that not help the situation to use limit/offset?