# MySQL & dotnet: efficiently update every row

Tags: .net, mysql, sequential, read-write

I embarked on something I thought would be straight-forward: Sequentially (row by row) read, calculate some values and update the same row before going on to the next for the entire table.

The context: one single flat table, **26 million records**, composite PK (4 numeric values).  **Physical table size 1.3 GB**.  The order in which the records are processed is irrelevant.  This will be done once only for the foreseeable future.  The calculation it too complex to be done in SQL (for me at least :-)

What is the recommended, efficient way to do this?

What I tried: Using `datareader` in `ADO.NET` (which hasn't got the good old VB6 resultset any longer which would have been so much simpler). Combining that with an update statement (statement.ExecuteNonQuery) within each `reader.Read()` loop was tricky as ADO.NET doesn't like that on the same connection.  So I had to open 2 connections.  (The update query uses the composite PK in the WHERE clause, which should potentially be fast, but still strikes me as inefficient since the cursor is already at the record I'm about to update.)

This approach sort of works but not with a reader based on `SELECT * FROM MyTable` query.  I had to use `LIMIT` to read chunks of a few thousand rows at a time to avoid timeout errors.  From early experiments I estimated the process to take **9 hours for the 26 million records**.  I set it up to run overnight, when I came back it had timed out again somewhere one third through the process. After re-starting I discovered that the LIMIT clause slows the `SELECT` query once the offset becomes bigger.  My new estimates for the remaining 65% are in excess of another 20 hours, possibly longer as the LIMIT offset increases.

There must be a better way!?

(I also tried the EF which was elegant but timed out of course :-)

Answer (score 0):

Updating the database in small batches (1000 or so records) is generally a good approach because it avoids locking rows (or pages) for too long, and avoids timeouts.  That part of the approach is great.

You can improve performance of LIMIT for large starting values.  There are various approaches.  The best I found to date involves not using LIMIT at all, but rather selecting primary key ranges

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1911210/141172

Comment: Thx 4 ur prompt reply, Eric. As for the locking aspect, apart from this being a single user db at this stage, but out of interest, are you saying that a select query locks all the records in its scope?  (The update statement handles one record at a time.)

Comment: I looked into those LIMIT performance improving approaches. I cannot define PK ranges easily due to the nature of the composite keys. I tried the JOIN "trick" explained [here](http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/) but, I suppose again due to composite keys (ON clause with 4 conditions), this was actually slower than plain LIMIT, and also renders the records in a slightly different order.  (I do no use ORDER BY, expecting, naively perhaps, reliable natural order.) Is there no low-level cursor-based approach for this simple problem?

Comment: Can you define an artificial PK on the table and treat the elements of the composite key as foreign keys?  There are many reasons (this being just one of them) to favor a short PK that is unique to the table.

Comment: The main purpose of the table is fast lookup by a combination of those 4 composites, which is working well. If I had an artificial PK I would probably need an index on the composites for performance reasons? Now, creating such a PK wouldn't that take as long as the sequential update process I'm currently trying to make faster?

Comment: You just create the PK column once, so the cost is amortized across the many updates you will do.  Yes, you would presumably need an index on the 4 composites.

Comment: Thx Eric, I will heed your advise for future development; i.e. it seems very costly to fix poor design at a later stage, e.g. just adding one blank column to a table of that size takes MySQL an hour or so, let alone creating a unique PK or building an index. I call it the "tyranny of magnitude", i,e. having a few hundreds or thousands of records won't show up design flaws, large records size are relentless.

I still like to know if there are any programmatic ways out there

Answer (score 0):

After the above discussion with Eric and further experiments, this is my conclusion of the saga:

- Relational databases are indeed not suited for sequential processing and any such processes will take performance hits when performed on relational DBMSs.
- At some stage during the history of databases, platforms like VB6 offered tools like the "Recordset" which enabled "cursor-based" traversing of tables, reading and updating records as you went along.  These used to work on supported providers like ODBC and OLE (and DBMS attached to these).  The recordset looked very tempting for the job at hand but is no longer available in ADO.NET (as of 2013)
- Small to medium size tables will forgive design errors.
- The OS caches entire data tables and as such masks DB ineffciencies while dealing with small to medium size tables
- Once table sizes (and/or number of rows) increase, the system starts to thrash and seems to behave abnormally.  It is likely to have been performing badly before but you will not have noticed it because of the points mentioned above.
- My method of using SELECT...LIMIT (to retrieve blocks of 1000 rows) came to a screeching halt at about 75% though the 26 million rows table; i.e. each SELECT of 1000 rows now taking minutes to complete.
- I have dabbled with emulating cursor-based recordset based on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8435/Simulating-Recordsets-with-ADO-NET only to find out that MySQL doesn't support UPDATE of cursors und only supports cursors inside stored procedures, which defeated the purpose, as my calculations had to be performed outside the DBMS. (It may work well for SQL Server)
- (As my table consisted of a 4-part composite key) I ended up creating a single artificial AutoIncrement key/index as Eric suggested, so I could traverse through the records using calculated ranges (e.g. 0-999, 1000-1999 etc.) which, unlike using LIMIT, was equally fast at the beginning and the end of the table traverse.  Creating the AutoIncrement field plus index/key (within one command) took MySQL a little under 1 hour (for 26+ million records at 150 bytes/record) on a slow 2-core Atom netbook.
- In the configuration described above the full traversal took about 9 hours for the 26+ million records, equal to my original estimate when LIMIT was timed at the beginning of the process.

Hope this may help anyone in a similar situation.  Comments are greatly appreciated.