# Why is MongoDB's skip() so slow and bad to use, while MySQL's LIMIT is so fast?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, limit, skip, nosql

Mongo's skip() is fine for small collections, but once you have a few thousand records it starts to become slow.

I would honestly like to know why a decent LIMIT-like function in a NoSQL database is so hard to do.

The only "solution" I keep reading about is using range-based queries. But for a lot of cases that is not a viable solution.

Comment: Skipping is only slow when you reach into the 100,000's of rows, it isn't always slow, but whereas SQL can do a range query on a hidden AI index MongoDB cannot, it has to read the documents/index to the point of the skip

Answer (score 5):

MySQL's `LIMIT` has similar challenges with large offsets.  A few examples from StackOverflow:

- [How can I speed up a MySQL query with a large offset in the LIMIT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243952)
- [Why does MYSQL higher LIMIT offset slow the query down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481388/).

The underlying problem with the efficiency of limit queries with large skip/offset values is that in order for the database query to get to the point where it can start returning records, a large number of index entries have to be skipped.  For a database with active writes (inserts/updates/deletes) this can also lead to some interesting paging side effects if you don't isolate the query or cache the results.

Range-based pagination is a more efficient approach that can take advantage of indexes, but as you noted it may not suit all use cases.  If you frequently need to skip thousands of records and find this too expensive you may want to adjust your data model, add some caching, or add usage limitations in your user interface.

For example, when paging through Google search results for a generic term there may be hundreds of millions of results.  If you keep clicking through pages you'll eventually discover there is a UI limit of 1,000 results (which may equate to 50-100 pages depending on how many results are filtered).  Another popular UI approach is [Continuous Scrolling](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/ContinuousScrolling) which avoids some of the common pagination issues (though creates other usability challenges).

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with skip(). Everything worked fine when my database was having fewer documents but performance started affecting when my document count was more than 10L.

I had to get rid of skip but then fetching specific count of data was a challenge to me. below blog helped me out.

https://scalegrid.io/blog/fast-paging-with-mongodb/